# How to get a specific random number out of three numbers in android

Tags: java, android, random

I have three numbers (25, 30 and 35). I want to get one random number out of these three numbers.

I know how to get a random number from a range, but in this case I have no idea how to get (randomly) one of those three numbers.

Does anyone have any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you add the three numbers to an array, then generate a random number between 0 and 2 which will be the index of the element?

Comment: @Ollie :- Can you provide example ?

Comment: an example? he told you exactly what to do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Ollie said in the comments, use an `array` and get the random value from that `array`.

```
package main.application;

import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] intArray = {25, 30, 35};

        int idx = new Random().nextInt(intArray.length);
        String random = "Value is " + (intArray[idx]);

        System.out.println(random);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is the right way to do it, but I think this will work.

If you can't understand something, just let me know, so I can explain it :)

I will give an example:

```
    int[ ] numbers = { 25,30,35 };
    int max = numbers.length;
    int random = (int)(Math.random() * max);
    int randomNumer = numbers[random];
```

Answer (score 1):

In kotlin, you can get the random number from the given set of numbers by using below code:

```
fun getRandomNumber(): Int {
    val secureRandom = SecureRandom()
    val intArray = intArrayOf(10, 15, 20)
    return intArray[secureRandom.nextInt(intArray.size)]
}
```